# Spidermonkey bytecode documentation

Tags: javascript, firefox, spidermonkey

I am looking for quite some time a documentation for all the spidermonkey's bytecodes, or at least something that tells me in general what a bytecode's purpose is.

Does anyone can recommend such resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's not a great story, but the best documentation we have (other than `jsopcode.tbl`, as Alex K. mentions) is the interpreter implementation (`jsinterp.cpp`). We've noted on several occasions that it would be helpful to newcomers to have a more formalized document, noting the stack state transitions and describing side effects. I've started one here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/Bytecodes

Feel free to drop in on #jsapi on irc.mozilla.org to ask about any that you'd like to see documented specifically!

Comment: Hmmm, discussion with the other developers seems to have general agreement we should have a nice comment on each case in the interpreter loop -- I'll be migrating the documentation there and will link from the wiki page when that's done.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll also check the IRC channel :-).
Obviously a nice doc for each JSOP would be extremely helpful for newbies!

Answer (score 1):

Download the source & look in `jsopcode.tbl` which will look like [this](http://www.assembla.com/code/d2bs/subversion/nodes/trunk/Core/Dependencies/SpiderMonkey/js32/jsopcode.tbl?rev=1157) (forked?) version.

Comment: I have this file, but it doesn't document the JSOPs. It says a few words on a few OPs, but its not *really* a documentation...

Comment: Nice answer! Here's the current link: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/jsopcode.tbl

Answer (score 0):

Many of the links in other answers are broken; [here](https://github.com/mozilla-spidermonkey/spidermonkey-embedding-examples/blob/esr78/docs/Bytecodes.md) is documentation of the opcodes in the SpiderMonkey embedder docs repository, which is automatically generated from [the source code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-esr78/source/js/src/vm/Opcodes.h).